# UnsatisfiedLinkError with executing a JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been developing some application which I can execute from Eclipse without any problems, all is good. But when I make a runnable JAR file and execute it I get the following message:

```
Catched MalformedURLException: Could not open InputStream for URL 'rsrc:gluegen-
rt_3-natives-windows-i586.jar', while TempJarCache.bootstrapNativeLib() of jar:r
src:gluegen-rt_3-natives-windows-i586.jar!/ (rsrc: + gluegen-rt_3-natives-window
s-i586.jar)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluege
n-rt in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoad
erBase.java:454)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.ja
va:59)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNIL
ibLoaderBase.java:90)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.j
ava:328)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrar
y(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:390)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$2.run(Platform.java:249)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.loadGlueGenRTImpl(Platform.java:231)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:183)
        at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:99)
        at org.jzy3d.global.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:12)
        at org.jzy3d.global.Settings.getInstance(Settings.java:21)
        at com.nda.fuzzy.views.SurfaceViewerFrame.<init>(SurfaceViewerFrame.java
:102)
        at com.nda.fuzzy.views.MainFrame$26.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:579)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown
Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

C:\>java -jar destination.jar
╠рьфрэш
Catched MalformedURLException: Could not open InputStream for URL 'rsrc:gluegen-
rt_3-natives-windows-i586.jar', while TempJarCache.bootstrapNativeLib() of jar:r
src:gluegen-rt_3-natives-windows-i586.jar!/ (rsrc: + gluegen-rt_3-natives-window
s-i586.jar)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluege
n-rt in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoad
erBase.java:454)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.ja
va:59)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNIL
ibLoaderBase.java:90)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.j
ava:328)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrar
y(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:390)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$2.run(Platform.java:249)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.loadGlueGenRTImpl(Platform.java:231)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:183)
        at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:99)
        at org.jzy3d.global.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:12)
        at org.jzy3d.global.Settings.getInstance(Settings.java:21)
        at com.nda.fuzzy.views.SurfaceViewerFrame.<init>(SurfaceViewerFrame.java
:102)
        at com.nda.fuzzy.views.MainFrame$26.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:579)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown
Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But when I extract my completed jar file into folder using WinRAR I see that gluegen-rt.jar is in folder and there is my manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar JTatto
 o.jar jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar gluegen-rt-natives-linux-arm
 v7hf.jar gluegen-rt_3.jar jogl-all-natives-linux-armv7hf_2.jar jgoodi
 es-forms-1.6.0.jar jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar jogl-all-natives
 -solaris-i586.jar gluegen-rt-natives-linux-armv7.jar org.jzy3d-0.9_2.
 jar swt.jar gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal_2.jar gluegen_2.jar j
 ogl-all-natives-linux-armv7_2.jar gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64_3.
 jar jogl-all-natives-windows-i586_3.jar gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd6
 4_3.jar jogl-all-natives-solaris-amd64_2.jar swt-debug.jar swt_2.jar 
 applet-launcher_3.jar gluegen-rt-natives-solaris-amd64_3.jar jgoodies
 -looks-2.5.2.jar org.jzyio-0.1.jar jogl-all-natives-linux-armv7hf.jar
  gluegen-rt-natives-solaris-i586_2.jar gluegen-rt-natives-linux-armv7
 _2.jar swt_3.jar jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar gluegen-rt-natives-l
 inux-i586_3.jar jogl-all-natives-linux-armv7_3.jar gluegen-rt-natives
 -solaris-amd64.jar jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal_2.jar jogl-all-n
 atives-windows-amd64_3.jar applet-launcher.jar jogl-all-natives-windo
 ws-amd64_2.jar junit.jar org.convexhull.jar jogl-all-natives-linux-am
 d64_3.jar log4j-1.2.16.jar jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar glue
 gen-rt-natives-macosx-universal_3.jar jogl-all-natives-linux-amd64.ja
 r jogl-all-natives-solaris-i586_3.jar gluegen-rt-natives-solaris-amd6
 4_2.jar opencsv-2.1_3.jar jogl-all-natives-solaris-amd64.jar gluegen-
 rt-natives-windows-i586.jar gluegen-rt-natives-solaris-i586.jar jogl-
 all_2.jar jogl-all-natives-linux-armv7.jar gluegen-rt-natives-linux-a
 rmv7hf_2.jar jogl-all-natives-windows-i586_2.jar gluegen-rt-natives-l
 inux-i586.jar gluegen-rt-natives-linux-i586_2.jar gluegen-rt-natives-
 windows-amd64.jar gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586_2.jar applet-launch
 er_2.jar swt-debug_2.jar opencsv-2.1_2.jar commons-math-2.2.jar jogl-
 all-natives-solaris-i586_2.jar gluegen-rt-natives-linux-armv7_3.jar j
 ogl-all-natives-linux-i586_2.jar gluegen.jar jogl-all-natives-linux-i
 586_3.jar gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64_2.jar gluegen-rt-natives-l
 inux-amd64.jar opencsv-2.1.jar gluegen_3.jar gluegen-rt-natives-linux
 -armv7hf_3.jar jogl-all-natives-linux-amd64_2.jar jgoodies-common-1.4
 .0.jar jogl-all-natives-solaris-amd64_3.jar org.convexhull_3.jar glue
 gen-rt_2.jar org.convexhull_2.jar gluegen-rt-natives-solaris-i586_3.j
 ar gluegen-rt.jar jogl-all_3.jar jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal_3.
 jar gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar gluegen-rt-natives-linux-
 amd64_2.jar org.jzy3d-0.9.jar jogl-all-natives-linux-armv7hf_3.jar jo
 gl-all.jar gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586_3.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: com.nda.fuzzy.Main
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Where is the mistake? Please, don't give me any links for tutorials, just help me understand the problem!

Comment: *"I see that gluegen-rt.jar is in folder"*  What 'folder'?  Note that directories on disk are not the same as paths in zip archives, and both are different to the 'window style representation' of a directory as seen in a folder.   Jars cannot be put inside Jars.